# If there a way to test a char to a class of user define character?

Tags: c++, types, char

Is there any way to define a type and do the following?

```
char c = 'a';
if (c == BRASSECHARTYPE)
{
     // do something if c is one of the following char [{()}]
}
```

Comment: `if (c == '[' || c == '{' ... and so on`?

Comment: I'm going to do this other and other in my code I was looking for something to clean this pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is lots of ways to do it:

Simple function:

```cpp
bool isOneOfChars(char ch, std::initializer_list<char> chars)
{
    return std::find(std::begin(chars), std::end(chars), ch) != std::end(chars);
}

bool isBrace(char ch)
{
    return isOneOfChars(ch, {'[', '{', '(', ')', '}'});
}
```

Fancy template with fold expression:

```cpp
template<char...Chars>
constexpr bool isOneOfChars(char ch)
{
    return ((Chars == ch) || ...);
}

constexpr bool isBrace(char ch)
{
     return isOneOfChars<'[', '{', '(', ')', '}'>(ch);
}
```

Or lookup table with designated initializes (clangs supports it):

```cpp
constexpr bool isBrace(char ch)
{
    constexpr bool braceTable[256] {
        ['['] = true, 
        ['{'] = true, 
        ['('] = true, 
        [')'] = true, 
        ['}'] = true,
    };

    return braceTable[static_cast<unsigned char>(ch)];
}
```

or any other solution.

https://godbolt.org/z/beGzq4snM

Answer (score 1):

You can use `std::string::find` to check if a character equals any of `[{()}]` :

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    char needle = 'c';
    std::string haystack = "[](){}";
    if (haystack.find(needle) != std::string::npos) {
        std::cout << needle << " was found in " << haystack << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm going to do this other and other in my code, which means I have to pass as an argument "haystack " everywhere right? anyway to make a type or an enum to do this test?

Comment: @Fractale do you want a function `bool is_bracket( char c)` ?

Comment: is it the cleanest way? I can do this function. I was hoping for something more elegant. if (c is in this group).